# How to get Stanford Deep Sentiment Leaf Sentiment

Tags: java, tree, nlp

I'm using the Stanford sentiment analysis part of the CoreNLP Java library. I figured out how to extract the sentiment of nodes using the answer to this question (stackoverflow.com/questions/23729829/sentiment-ranked-nodes-in-dependency-parse-with-stanford-corenlp/25935721). I need the sentiment of each node, including leaves and I'm getting values of -1 for the sentiment of leaves (which should be in the range [0,4]).

Is there a way to get the sentiment of the leaves? I saw in the online demo that use to be online that the leaf nodes of the trees had sentiment value. I feel like the RNTN should be able to output sentiment values. I'm using the RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat roundabout answer would be to take each leaf and provide it separately to the sentiment annotator as a single word sentence. Then you can take the sentiment assigned to the "sentence" as the leaf sentiment.

There has to be a better way to do this, though.